# Remove Add-in from Office 2016 for Mac

Tags: ms-office

After installing an add-in (.xla) which worked once, I'm trying to remove it so I can install an updated version.

So far I've:

- deleted the .xla
- removed the check box in Tools > Add-ins
- removed it from the list
- Quit Excel completely
- reopened Excel.

I get an error that Excel can't find the plugin, it's back in the Add-ons list, and the Add-ins toolbar is still there with the Add-ins buttons.

Did all the same stuff again, this time with a reboot thrown in. No change.

Where is it storing this? 
I looked through the plists in the Excel bundle, but couldn't find any references.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do this through "My Add-Ins"

In the Insert Menu, select Add-Ins and then the submenu "My Add-Ins"

[image]

Click the 3 dots in the upper right hand corner of the Add-In you wish to remove.  Then click "Remove".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks - you may get a warning (yellow bar with text) telling you that the add on could not be deleted and to try again. Simply hit REFRESH and it should show you a list off add on's you still have active minus the one's you removed.

Answer (score 2):

1. In Excel, choose **Tools>Templates and Add-ins**.
2. In the *Global Templates and Add-ins* section, select the problem add-in. Make a note of its location under **Full path:**, then close Excel.
3. In the Finder, hold down the **Alt** key while clicking on the **Go** menu and choosing **Library**. Your user library folder will open. Navigate to the path you noted in the last step.
4. Delete the add-in file.
5. Restart Excel and check that you've gotten rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook on Mac, Go to top toolbar 'Get Add-ins'-->'My add-ins'--> Click the ... button to see the remove add-in option. [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the Zoom / RingCentral add-in for Outlook for Mac, you need a different method.

From https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372659/113440 ...

> The zoom plug-in / add-in is not provided by the Microsoft store, rather installed by zoom itself, so you won't find it in the Microsoft store > my add-ins area. If you go to finder > applications, you will see a folder called 'Zoom plugin for Outlook', in that folder is an uninstall icon. Close outlook, uninstall, and voila....zoom gone!
>
> This has been especially important since the zoom client no longer works in macOS Catalina, so it's useless to keep it in outlook.