# How to uninstall Zoom outlook client from outlook 365 from Mac

Tags: macos, ms-office, zoom.app

I have searched everywhere but cannot find any way to remove this Outlook addin. It is a very annoying and keep on sending update alerts every 5 minutes.

I have contacted the MS Office Support and they said the following:

> Navigate to the ribbon under 'Home' tab > click on 'Get add-ins' option > click on 'manage add-ins/My Add-ins' option in the left column > try removing the Add-ins that you would like to remove.

But there is no option called "Get add-ins". Attaching the image:

[image]

I tried searching for anything with Add-in in every menu and every ribbon and still didn't get any answer.

MS Office support didn't reply back after this and because probably even they don't know how to fix it.

Comment: People can downvote me all they want but if you guys have the answer then please let me know because otherwise you are just being a schmuck. Don't just downvote me because you think this is a stupid question.

Comment: It's not always easy to see what causes downvotes, so I won't even guess (the downvotes have been cast before you've added the details about contacting MS Office Support which probably explains them though). But your question could still benefit from more details about whether you tried to search for the "Get add-ins" option in other ribbons and menus, about whether you got back to MS Office Support asking for clarification and similar things.

Comment: @nohillside That's true but I think people should reveal what is lacking in the question when they downvote. And this is because I think the main reason why this website exists is to help people and not to measure the quality of the question asked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found it! The zoom plug-in / add-in is not provided by the Microsoft store, rather installed by zoom itself, so you won't find it in the Microsoft store > my add-ins area. If you go to finder > applications, you will see a folder called 'Zoom plugin for Outlook', in that folder is an uninstall icon. Close outlook, uninstall, and voila....zoom gone!

This has been especially important since the zoom client no longer works in macOS Catalina, so it's useless to keep it in outlook.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I almost lost hope but this was spot on.

Comment: The Zoom plugin is also responsible for Outlook crashing when you try to take it into Full Screen Mode (via window''s green button). Per a chat with Microsoft Support:
```We have investigated on this and found it to be an issue on Zoom's end. *Mac OS 10.15 Catalina does not support plug-ins, including the Microsoft Outlook Plugin for Zoom. `

Comment: The uninstall app was the first thing I tried, and it hangs immediately after asking me for a user & password.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug in the Outlook interface where for some users the "Store" button that is supposed to give you access to the add-ins doesn't show up in the ribbon.

I have found the following method to be easy to work around it:

1. Open Microsoft Word instead
2. Select the "Insert" ribbon
3. Click "My Add-ins"

You'll now see a list of installed add-ins as well as a link to the store. You should be able to uninstall the Zoom add-in from here.

It seems that some users have luck getting the Store icon back into Outlook itself by doing this in Excel - and yes, it sounds odd, but it needs to be Excel:

1. Open Excel
2. In the Template Gallery, choose your avatar at the top left
3. Click "Sign Out"
4. Close Excel (shut it down completely)
5. Open Excel again and the Template Gallery comes up
6. Click to "Sign in"
7. Click the "Store" button, then "Add-ins Store" and then "Outlook"
8. Add any Outlook add-in
9. Close Excel

Now the "Store" button should become visible in the Home ribbon in Excel.